# Is there any other purpose of "dictionary.get" function in Python with two elements in it, apart from checking for a variable in the list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I thougt it could store the answer for the case when user inputs a wrong key in it, like this:

```
month_conversion.get("Git", "Not a valid key")
month_conversion = input()
```

So, if user input "Git" it would print out "Not a valid key"
But it doesn't store it and just prints out "None"

Comment: That code is pretty nonsensical. What do you expect this to do? This won't magically handle any input the user does. The second line is simply overwriting the variable `month_conversion` with user input, the first line does absolutely nothing in relation to that.

Comment: to print it you have to assign to variable `result = month_conversion.get("Git", "Not a valid ` key")` and `print(result)` or `if result == "Not a valid key": result = input()`

Comment: it is useful to get default value if it doesn't exist in dict `result = dictionary.get("Git", "some default value")`

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict): To check if a key exists in a dict there is `key in dict` syntax.

The purpose of `.get()` method is that the get with `[]` operators will raise a `KeyError` exception and this function is meant to not raise `KeyError` in case that key does not exists.